# Angular 2: ngFor index only increment if case met

Tags: angular, ngfor

Let's say I have an array of objects that I'm looping through:

```
arr = [ {a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 1} ]
```

and I want to display the index of the object in my view, but I only want the index to increment if a condition is met.  Something like `a == 1`.  So if I had some code such as:

```
<!-- I know this won't work -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index">{{ i }}</li>
</ul>
```

...it would display as:

```
<li>0</li>
<li></li>
<li>1</li>
```

Comment: You'll need a variable in your component to keep track manually and externally. Can provide example if needed/wanted.

Comment: Just add a property to your objects inside your array that contains the conditional increment and calculate the value that goes into that property when it needs to be calculated inside a function in your component. `[ {a: 1, b: 0}, {a: 2}, {a: 1, b: 1} ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.component.ts:

```
arr:{a:number}[] = [{a: 1},{a: 2},{a: 1} ];
```

app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index"> 
    <div *ngIf="obj.a == 1">
    <li>{{i}}</li>
    </div>
  </div>  
</ul>
```